# Задача Олимпиадная

Tags: алгоритм

Есть 2 массива четырех-буквенных слов:

1. Массив плохих слов;
2. Массив слов которые необходимо проверить.

Необходимо убрать из второго массива все "плохие" слова, и вывести в отсортированном виде. Слово является плохим, если хотя бы 3 буквы этого слова совпадают с теми же 3 буквами одного из слов первого массива. Слова состоят из русских маленьких букв.

**Какое есть более универсальное решение, чем перебирать в лоб?**

*p.s. Есть пару идей, но пока еще не додумал и не реализовал.*

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ все слова состоят из 4 букв. И совпадение букв должно быть по позициям. т.е. для слова "щука" будут следующие плохие слова: `"_ука"`, `"щ_ка"`, `"щу_а"`, `"щук_"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я думаю задача решается префиксным деревом http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Из словаря надо составить дерево, в котором переход по пути "Х->У->..". будет означать "плохое слово" а перехода по пути Х->У->К не будет. Таким образом чек каждого слова будет просиходить за константное время

Answer (score 4):

Реализовал свою идею, работает достаточно быстро :)

**Идея:**

- Для начала научимся (научим программу) преобразовывать слово в число:

`abcd = a*33^3 + b*33^2 + c*33 + d`

- Создадим 4 словаря, плохих слов, которые должны будут удовлетворять условию (4 вариации по 3 буквы), т.е. **abc**, **abd**, **acd**, **bcd**. Один словарь будет размерностью `33^3 +33^2+33` и содержать одно булевское значение, обозначающее это сочетание плохого слова или нет. При обработки плохих слов заполняем данные словари.
- При проверки слов на плохизну вычисляем также 4 числа и проверяем их в массиве. Если в одном из массивов встречается true то это плохое слово.

**Пример:**

Плохое слово: ААБВ / 0 + 0 + 33 + 2

Составляем 4 числа: 0+0+33, 0+0+2, 0+33+2, 0+33+2.

Массивы поиска: A1[33] = true, A2[2] = true, A3[35] = true, A4[35] = true

Проверяем слова:

```
ААБГ
> 0+0+33+4 
> 33, 4, 37, 37
// это плохое слово, т.к. A1[33] == true

ААВГ
> 0+0+66+4
> 66, 4, 70, 70
// это не плохое слово, т.к. A1[66] == A2[4] == A3[70] == A4[70] == false
```

**Сравнение**

Далее создал решение поставленной задачи в лоб, сгенерировал входные данные - словарь плохих слов из всевозможных вариантов (более 1 млн. слов), и проверяемых слов 100.000

Программа работающая в лоб выполнила задачу за 480 секунд, а по изложенному алгоритму 0,5 секунды.

Comment: Не очень. 

- Словарь получается слишком жирный, если букв например 6, и сравнивать надо по 5 буквам, то получим расход памяти O(33^5) * 6 ?

- Если у нас в словаре 1 слово, то нам всё равно надо инстанцировать бешенный массив, который почти полностью занят false-ами.

- В общем вся идея в том, чтобы проверять слово на хорошесть за константное время. Префиксные деревья делают это за то же константное время, пусть и чуть медленнее, но потребляют НАААМНОГО меньше памяти...

Comment: Если уж мы память не экономим, то просто тройки надо сложить в HashMap и не париться :)

Comment: @AndrewFrolov да, согласен :)

Answer (score -1):

Вот как я попробовал реализовать задачу на Java:

```
List<String> ploxieSlova = { "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" };
List<String> horoshieSlova = {  "5555", "6666", "7777", "8888" };

List<String> spisok = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String st : horoshieSlova) {
    for (String st2 : plohieSlova) {
        if (compare(st, st2) < 75) spisok.add(st); //Если хорошее слово не состоит из 75% плохого слова, то добавим его в список
    }
}

Collections.sort(spisok);

public double compare(string a, string b)
{
if (a == b) return 100;
if ((a.Length == 0) || (b.Length == 0)) return 0;

double maxLen = a.Length > b.Length ? a.Length: b.Length;
int minLen = a.Length < b.Length ? a.Length: b.Length;
int sameCharAtIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) 
{
    if (a[i] == b[i]) sameCharAtIndex++;
}
return sameCharAtIndex / maxLen * 100;
}
```

Comment: Минус за квадратичную сложность в топике про олимпиадные задачки :)

Comment: @AndrewFrolov, а что тут вы сложного увидели?

Comment: ох! http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @AndrewFrolov много букв, не читал. И на будущее: пользуйтесь bit.ly

Comment: @SuperCreeper, смысл в том что у вас решение "в лоб": два цикла, один вложен в другой. Вычислительная сложность такого алгоритма растет квадратично: для словаря длиной n придется делать n^2 проверок, а это очень медленно, когда речь идет об алгоритме поиска.

Comment: @Nofate, в задаче ничего не было сказано про требования ко времени вычисления, поэтому я предложил то, что смог.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, но автор открытым текстом просит 

> Какое есть более универсальное решение, чем перебирать в лоб?

Да и название темы "Олимпиадная задача." как бы намекает...

Comment: @Nofate, перебирать в лоб, это когда
`if (word == "mxxxx") ...
else if (word == "pxxxx")
else if (word == "zxxxxx")
else if (word == "exxx")`

А я предлагаю более совершенный механизм.
Если хотите, то минусуйте сколько душе угодно. Моё дело предложить вариант ответа. Да и вообще, не любят  здесь меня, мб мне просто уйти с Хэшкода?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, вы как раз это и делаете, только в цикле.

И не беспокойтесь из-за пустяков. Вы предложили далеко не оптимальное решение, вам указали почему. Просто поверьте более опытным коллегам и примите это. Никто лично против вас ничего не имеет. Оценивают здесь не людей, а ответы и то, как они соотносятся с вопросами. А минусы все когда-нибудь отхватывали, это не повод давить "Тревогу". Еще насобираете плюсов - никуда не убегут.

 
PS. Лично я вас не минусовал.

Comment: спасибо за хорошее настроение :)

> перебирать в лоб, это когда ...

> А я предлагаю более совершенный механизм